# Monge-Ampere type Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I've come across the following equation in my work:
$$
u_{tt} = \det(\textrm{Hess }  u),
$$
where $u=u(t,x,y)$ is a function of 3 variables and

$$   \textrm{Hess } u=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   u_{tt} & u_{tx} & u_{ty}\\
   u_{xt} & u_{xx} & u_{xy} \\
u_{yt} & u_{yx} & u_{yy}
  \end{array} } \right].
$$

I have not been able to find much on this equation (I know there's a big literature on $\det(\textrm{Hess }u)= f$ though) so hoping someone can tell me something/anything about this equation or give me references.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure the Hessian matrix is taken for the time variable as well? Usually the $\nabla$ just referers to the spartial variables (in this case x and y)

Comment: Yes, I know, it's a bit strange but the hessian on the rhs is taken for the time variable too

Comment: Any linear function is a solution. A function that is quadratic in $t,x,y$ is also a solution provided it satisfies the obvious determinant identity.

Comment: @HansEngler yes, thanks.